# Use calculated / scalar value in LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, openaccess

I'm using LINQ on a Telerik OpenAccess generated data model, to setup a search query and get the results. This all works very well and the code looks very nice. 
But now i need to add one more thing, and i'm not sure how to.
The products i'm selecting should have a different price for each customer. The price depends on some other values in 2 other SQL tables. Right now i have the price calculation in a SQL scalar function, but i'm not sure on how to use that in combination with my LINQ.

My goal is to retrieve all data in one database roundtrip, and to be able to sort on this calculated price column as well.

Right now i have something like:

```
var products = (from p in Products select p);
if(searchOption)
   products = products.Where(product => product.Name.Contains(searchOption));
products = products.OrderByDescending(product => product.Name);
products = products.Skip(pageNr * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

I can, of course, use all properties of my Product class, but i want to be able to use a new virtual/calculated property, let say: Product.CalculatedPrice as well.

I have a feeling it should look a bit like this.

```
(from p in Products
select new {
    productId = p.ProductId,
    name = p.Name,
    calculatedPrice = CalculatedValueFromStoredProcedure/OrScalarFunction(p.ProductId, loggedInCustomerId)
});
```

Best Regards, Tys

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but won't this do: `product => product.Name.Contains(searchOption) && product.CalculatedPrice < 100`

Comment: That would do, but, the problem is, the CalculatedPrice is not there yet. And that is what my question is about, how to get / select that calculated price, in the same linq query?

Comment: What calculation are you trying to do?  If it is simple addition/multiplication, then you should be able to just add that in to the Linq expression.

Comment: The calculation is looks up different values in different tables, and if a specific value exists, it looks up another value, otherwise, again, it goes for another value in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research i've found out that what i want to do is NOT possible in combination with the Telerik OpenAccess ORM! So i've created a workaround that pre-calculates the values i need, put them in a table and join my selection with the contents of that table. 
For now, that's the best possible solution i've found.

Answer (score 1):

[.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743.aspx) allows you to create a dynamic type, in which you can extend the product with the calculated price

```
    products.Select(i => new { Product = i, CalculatedPrice = 100})
```

or in your initial line:

```
    var products = (from p in Products select new { Product = p, CalculatedPrice = 100 });
```

Comment: This is going in to the right direction, but now i don't want a fixed price of 100, but i need to retrieve that value from the database. With a stored procedure or function. Is that possible?

Comment: You can add sp's to the Linq to SQL editor, just drag and drop the sp to the dbml file. Then you will be able to use the Sp from the DataContext inside the Select